# Least square plane fit cubic surface to 3d points

Tags: regression, surfaces, least-squares

I have point cloud and want to get cubic surface fit from it. The cubic polynomial surface equation is ($Ax^2 + By^2 + Cx^3 + Dx^2y + Exy^2 + Fy^3$). I want to get the value of $A, B, C, D, E$ & $F$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, on this site we use MathJaX to format our maths. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/145141) you can find a basic tutorial.

Comment: This is multilinear regression

Comment: What you are calling an equation is not an equation – an equation has an equals sign in it.

Answer (score 0):

So your model is $z=Ax^2 + By^2 + Cx^3 + Dx^2y + Exy^2 + Fy^3+\epsilon$, where, lets assume at this point that the errors terms are uncorrelated with $\mathbb{E}\epsilon=0$ and finite variance. So, you have to gather at least $n=8$ data points of the form $(z_i, x_i, y_i)$ (preferably much more than $8$). Then construct a design matrix of order $n\times 7$ of the following form 
$$
[\mathrm{1},x^2, y^2, x^3, x^2y, xy^2, y^3], 
$$
and then, using your favorite software, you should regress $\mathrm{z}$ on this vectors to obtain the OLS estimators of $A, B, C,...$

Comment: I tried this way but still not getting the correct answer......